# How to organize multiple protocol buffer files in git submodule?

Tags: import, path, protocol-buffers, code-generation, git-submodules

I'm sharing .proto files across multiple projects using git-submodules.

Now my question is how to setup the imports properly?

In a microservice environment all service-repositories have a git-submodule containing the shared .proto files:

- git.dev/**fooservice**

  - proto (contains `git.dev/proto` as submodule)
  - ... some java code
- git.dev/**barservice**

  - proto (contains `git.dev/proto` as submodule)
  - ... some go code
- git.dev/**bazservice**

  - proto (contains `git.dev/proto` as submodule)
  - ... some javascript code
- git.dev/**proto**

  - shared

    - shared.proto
  - fooservice

    - fooservice.proto (imports `shared/shared.proto`)
  - barservice

    - barservice.proto (imports `shared/shared.proto`)

The typical header of a service proto file currently looks like this:

`git.dev/proto/fooservice/fooservice.proto`

```
syntax = "proto3";

package abc.foo;

import "shared/shared.proto";

option go_package = "foopb";
option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_outer_classname = "FooProto";
option java_package  = "com.abc.foo";
```

#### Question 1: Import path

- Having it `import "shared/shared.proto";` works for linting of the git.dev/**proto** repo, but causes import-problems during code generation.
- Having it `import "proto/shared/shared.proto";` works for code generation in the service-repos but of course causes linting problems in the git.dev/**proto** repo
- ***Should the import statement contain the `proto` folder?***

#### Question 2: go_package Option

- to build the go stubs we currently use prototool to and set the `go_options.import_path` to e.g. `git.dev/fooservice` which generates correct golang import paths
- another option would be to run something like

  - `for x in proto/**/*.proto; do protoc -Iproto --go_out=plugins=grpc,paths=source_relative:src/proto $x; done` but this does not result in valid golang import paths as long as I don't add the full git path to the go_package option. Doing that of course conflicts with the git-submodule approach (which git repo path to choose, /proto or /*service.git ?).
- ***What's best practice using go_package in combination with git-submodules?***

#### Question 3: submodules and 3rd-party tools

- Is using git-submodules and 3rd-party tools like prototool the right way to work with proto files across multiple projects?

Thanks!

Comment: In regards to submodules, we have run into problems with submodules: transitive dependencies you maybe have a scenario where 2 different stubs use the same shared submodule but with different versions... We are moving away from Submodules and going with a metadata file that describes git dependencies and their versions along with a CLI to resolve them locally.

Comment: Thanks for the input - did you work with golang - if so, how did you resolve the import problem?

Comment: using https://github.com/jacebrowning/gitman so that we can organize any dependency in a directory structure we need for the protos